# How do I use a Linux alias in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux, alias

The real question I have is: how do I run Ruby in the existing shell rather than the subshell the Ruby process creates?

In my .chsrc file I have

```
alias ll 'ls -lrth'
```

Here's some quick Ruby code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts `alias ll`
```

Here's what happens when I run it:

```
./newrubytest.rb:2:in ``': No such file or directory - alias (Errno::ENOENT)
    from ./newrubytest.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Here's some information I found about existing shells vs subshells: http://ss64.com/bash/source.html

Comment: I think it is not even a problem with a subshell. `alias` should be found in the PATH and executable for a ruby script: ```ruby -e 'puts `alias ll`' #=> /usr/bin/alias: line 4: alias: ll: not found```

Comment: This link would be of importance: http://askubuntu.com/questions/98782/how-to-run-an-alias-in-a-shell-script#answer-98796 Shell functions and aliases are limited to the shell and do not work in executed shell scripts

Comment: ruby -e 'puts `alias ll`'
    -e:1:in ``': No such file or directory - alias ll (Errno::ENOENT)
        from -e:1:in `<main>'

Comment: `ruby` and `bash` are completely different languages. You cannot do what you want...

Comment: Obviously I can't "source" a Ruby file, but is there some way from Ruby I can run the command in the existing shell that Ruby was run from?